# Magento Dataflow profile not working after upgraded to 1.7

Tags: magento, export, magento-1.7

Morning internets,

Desperately need some help from a clever magento person.

Have created a new profile as well as trying to run existing profiles but in every case the popup window just gives this but does not get any further:-

Starting profile execution, please wait...
 Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data

I just don't know where to start to trace this.  I have recopied a clean download over the top of the install so there are no files missing.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

UPDATE
Each time the profile runs the dataflow_batch_export table is populated with 55 products.  Investigated the 55th & 56th products, saved and rerun and the process got a bit further.  Maybe this is a data corruption somewhere?  So editing each product which seemed to cause a problem got as far as 350 products exported to the table before it then reverted to only 142 products exported.
Edited that one and the products either side but now won't go any further.

Still baffled, brain hurts, I want my mummy.

Comment: this process goes through ajax. so if there is some ajax error, then it doesn't shown in browser and ajax loading image will not hide.

Comment: check your developer toolbar console for Javascript and/or other errors

Comment: Already checked.  Nothing in the console.

Comment: Customers are exporting fine, it is just products that will not start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Solved totally random problem.

AheadWorks featured products module v2.2 left over from previous install had some remnant attributes.  Attributes removed and export working perfectly.